# Do users need to create an account to read/write to Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an app that has Firebase as its database. The app shouldn't need the user to create an account to use it, but I want the user to be able to read/write their data onto the database (so maybe they have to create an account?).

Do I **have** to make the users create an account in order to use Firebase?

My problem is that my security rules are read/write are allowed for everyone (which I know is wrong, but how do I change them and not need users to create an account?) Maybe that's the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It is best to ask them to create an account

Although:

- it can be a non-real email address and
- there is anonymous auth also available

It sounds like you need the app to remember that user's particular data, so that when they return to the app, it is still their data (and not someone else's) that is being accessed.

To achieve that, we need each person's data to be stored in a different place in Firebase. Traditionally, this is by having them log in to some kind of system, most conveniently Firebase itself, and then the data stored in a branch of the database defined by their user Id.

Without logging in, you could simply ask the user for an identifier, such as "Bob" or "Carol", and then store their data under their identifier. The Firebase database would therefore have the following structure.

```
users/Bob/highScore: 3000
users/Bob/level: 7
users/Carol/highScore: 5050
users/Carol/level: 9
```

However this is not secure because there is nothing stopping Carol coming to the app and saying she is "Bob". Any such client-side activity you carry out to attempt to identify the user is not really authentication (in the opinion of Firebase) because all client-side activities can be faked relatively easily.

#### Firebase Authentication

The standard solution is to use Firebase to authenticate each user (see the Firebase authentication [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) for this), and give your app a user Id (such as "8769dsg6f8g7698769876sdgs9") which is unique and known (by Firebase) to be correct.

#### Firebase security rules

You can then lock down the database using [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) so that only user 8769dsg6f8g7698769876sdgs9 can write to any of the `users/8769dsg6f8g7698769876sdgs9/....` part of the database.

If you don't use Firebase to authenticate the user, Firebase will treat the user as unauthenticated and you will have no way to restrict each user to their own section of the database. Either you leave it wide open (to hackers etc!) or users will not be able to access their own personal data on it.

#### They can use a FAKE email address and password

If your concern is that they won't want to give out their real email address, you can ask them to make up any email address, e.g. mickeyMouse49857430679304@hotmail.com, and set a password. There is no obligation on your app to contact them on that email address or verify that the email address is correct.

Whenever they come back to the app, or access it on another device, they need to remember the fake email address and password.

Of course, if they lose their password, there is no way to reset it.

#### Anonymous Authentication, but at risk of losing access

The legendary Frank von Puffelen of Firebase, himself, has added a remark about [Anonymous Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth), in the comments below. From what I understand, this avoids them having to make up a fake email address.

I think the weakness of this is that if they lose their local web storage (e.g. if they manually wipe it, or move to another device), there is no way for them to re-access the same account, unless they have planned ahead by adding an email/pw to the anonymous account.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you! So if a user didn't want to create an account with their actual email address, I could do it via anonymous authentication and then somehow save the anonymous auth to be saved to the phone, so when they open the app, it only lets them see **their** info? And then that auto satisfies the Firebase rules to be for 'authenticated users' only?

Comment: No, because Firebase means authenticated *by Firebase*. If it is just something store locally, it is not really valid, as that is relatively easy to be spoofed. Whatever happens in Javascript on the client can be easily hacked.

Comment: Right okay, so I'll just have to make it so the user _has_ to make an account and do as you said above, thank you for your help!

Comment: (Cheers. See extra bit i have added just now about using a fake email address, if you think they are going to be shy to use the real one.)

Comment: Thank you for that extra, I suppose I could save their fake email to User Defaults so they would be signed in automatically. (It's an iOS app and I know how to save info there). Thanks again

Comment: Instead of creating a fake email address, consider using [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth). This gives the user a non-spoofable UID without requiring them to provide credentials. You can use the UID to assocaite data with the user, control their data access, **and** you can allow the user to [upgrade their account by signing in later with email+password or another provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) and for example take their account to a different device.

Answer (score 1):

The only real way to have security per-user data storage is to use [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) to sign in the user, and write [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) to protect the database so that each user can only access their own data.  There are no secure alternatives to this for Realtime Database.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! Would the best way to add an 'anonymous authentication' through Firebase? That way, they don't have to create an actual account with their email address, but it still satisfies the Firebase Security Rules?

Comment: Sure, but that account is limited to the device where the account was created.  And it's fragile, because the account will disappear if the app is uninstalled, its storage is cleared, or the device is reset.  Anonymous accounts are meant to be a low-friction way to get the user started, with the intent to upgrade them eventually to a full account.